# GPS-USB receiver which works with gps-share under Linux

Tags: usb, linux, gps

I am looking for recommendation on USB-connected GPS receiver (preferrably cable >= 3m and antenna at the end) which will work with [gps-share](https://github.com/zeenix/gps-share) (and thus GeoClue, if I understand correctly) under Linux. I found [Navilock  NL-8012U](https://www.navilock.de/produkt/62524/merkmale.html?g=1286) fitting the specs, but [this issue](https://github.com/zeenix/gps-share/issues/3) made me unsure whether Navilock is a good choice.

Comment: Maybe you can consider some DIY solution, based on Raspberry Pi, GPS module (all this battery powered)?

Comment: I would like to avoid this, enough work on other parts of the project. I am now considering a receiver from gpswebshop.com (Columbus), they describe it here: https://gpswebshop.com/blogs/tech-support-by-os-linux/how-to-connect-an-usb-gps-receiver-with-a-linux-computer

Comment: For me the work from your link is not so small. Nevertheless check here for GPS Raspberry Pi NTP Server: https://blog.networkprofile.org/gps-backed-local-ntp-server/